# Publicar en la AppStore app de flutter

Tags: flutter, ios, aplicación-movil, applet

Estoy laborando en una empresa "POLLOS", ya culminé la app está pendiente para publicar en las tiendas.

Para subir en la AppStore y que se muestre en el nombre de desarrollador el nombre de la empresa(POLLOS), así tal cual se muestra en las imágenes adjuntas?

1.- Con mi cuenta personal ID de Apple lo publico? o es que tengo que registrar la empresa en alguna sección.

2.- O es que tengo que crear una cuenta ID de Apple con un correo coportativo(movil@miempresa.com) y a partir de ahí genero y le indico que deseo ser desarrollador apple) para la licencia de developer de Apple.

Me pueden apoyar por favor con esta consulta?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!

Desafortunadamente debes tener una empresa legal con su ID y crearte una cuenta de desarrollador de empresa...

No es como Google, que es más flexible.

Es por eso que ves muchos desarrolladores en App Store con su nombre personal, ya que muchos empiezan independiente.